# CSS: RGB transparency not working?

Tags: javascript, css, transparency, rgb

I'm sure this is a stupid question but whenever I put in a value for transparency, it goes completely transparent.

```
.studentHelp#sidebar{
  position:fixed;
  left:-300px;
  top:30px;
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgb(0,255,255,0.3); // this should be opaque?!?!?!
}
```

I've tried setting

```
'opaque: 0.3'
```

but then all of the child elements inherit the transparency? Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey neau try using rgba and goodluck!

Answer (score 5):

should be:

```
background-color:rgba(0,255,255,0.3);
```

note the rgb**a**